# What is the differantial equation which has the particular solution $y_p=(x^2-1)e^{-x}+x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the lowest ordered differantial equation which has the particular solution $y_p=(x^2-1)e^{-x}+x$?

For $e^{-x}$ we have $(D+1)$
and for $xe^{-x}\to(D+1)^2$, 
For $x^2e^{-x}\to (D+1)^3$

I dont know how to combine them. answer is $(D+1)^3D^2y=0$ btw.

Comment: hint: $(x^2 - 1)e^{-x} = x^2e^{-x} - e^{-x}$

Comment: isnt it $(D+1)^3-(D+1)+D^2$?

Comment: Hint (systematic, no ingeniosity required): expand the LHS of $$\left(\frac{y_p(x)-x}{x^2-1}e^x\right)'=0$$ and cancel the factor $e^x$ to get (a differential equation similar to) $$(x^2-1)y'_p+(x^2-2x-1)y_p-x^3+x^2+x+1=0.$$

Comment: could you please make an answer :(

Comment: @Did: Given that the answer provided by the OP at the end of the question is an operator of order 5, I suspect that the OP is looking for an equation with *constant* coefficients (even though this is not explicitly mentioned in the question). Otherwise the $0$-th order equation $y = y_p$ would do...

Comment: @mayilma: Have you studied the Fourier transform in the context of the theory of distributions? If so, remember that polynomials and differential operators with constant coefficients are dual to each other through the Fourier transform, and this shows a potential approach to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Given: $$y_p = (x^2-1)e^{-x}+x$$
Finding the total derivatives we obtain:
$$dy = [e^{-x}(1+2x-x^2) + 1]dx$$
$$\therefore \frac{dy}{dx} = 1 - e^{-x}(x^2-2x-1)$$
$$\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{is the required differential equation}  $$